# If $f(g(x))=\sqrt {x^2-2x+8}$ and $f(x)=\sqrt x,$ find $g(x)$.

Tags: functions, function-and-relation-composition

> If $f(g(x))=\sqrt {x^2-2x+8}$ and $f(x)=\sqrt x,$ find $g(x)$.

There is no example like this in my math book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe it will help you to see what $g(x)$ must be by the following: $$f(g(x)) = \sqrt {g(x)} = \sqrt{x^2 - 2x + 8}$$

Spoiler:

> $$g(x) = x^2 - 2x + 8$$

Comment: @amWhy. So is the answer x^2-2x+8?

Comment: @CSES: Yes, that's $g(x)$.

Comment: Yes, $g(x) = x^2 - 2x + 8$.

Comment: I guess I thought it was going to be harder. Thanks amWhy and @rubik

Comment: You're welcome, CSES!

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

$$f(x)=\sqrt x\implies f(x^2-2x+8)=\sqrt{x^2-2x+8}$$